# Unit testing Scala using mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm very much new to doing unit testing in Scala using Mockito. I'm getting an error in the `thenReturn` statement.

```
it should "read null when readFromPostgresTarget is called with some 
         random driver" in {

Given("a null query is sent as query")
       val query = ""
       val pgObject = mock[PersistenceObject]
       val postgresPersistenceObject = 
       mock[PostgressPersistenceServiceTrait]
       val mockDF = mock[DataFrame]

When("it is passed to readFromPostgresTarget")
        when(postgresPersistenceObject.readFromPostgresTarget(any[String],mock[Spark 
                                      Session], pgObject)).thenReturn(mockDF)

        assert(postgresPersistenceObject.readFromPostgresTarget(query, 
                             sparkSession, pgObject) === any[DataFrame])

Then("a null value should be returned")
        verify(postgresPersistenceObject, times(1))
}
```

I'm getting the error-

```
overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives:
  (x$1: Unit,x$2: Unit*)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[Unit] <and>
  (x$1: Unit)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[Unit]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
                .thenReturn(mockDF)
```

I tried making the `mockDF` in `thenReturn(mockDF)` to `thenReturn(any[DatafRame])`, it's not fixing the issue.

I tried passing a `SparkSession` instead of the mock it isn't working.

I can't figure what mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Note that for testing JDBC based persistence, you could have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) test framework (I'm contributor of)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid those problems (related to Scala/Java interop) you should use [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)